# How to display numbers with decimal part equal to 0 as a whole number in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, integer, decimal

| Column1 | Amount | DesiredOutput |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 85.00 | 85 |
| Item2 | 52.25 | 52.25 |
| Item3 | 36.85 | 36.85 |
| Item4 | 67.00 | 67 |

I want to be able to display numbers with decimal parts equal to 0 as whole numbers but the ones with decimal parts not equal to 0 as decimal numbers. I've tried this code but it didn't work:

```
 CASE 
      WHEN Amount % 1 = 0 THEN CAST (AMOUNT AS INT)
      ELSE Amount    
 END as [DesiredOutput]
```

The `Amount` column is `DECIMAL` type

Comment: That is something for your presentation layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: As a side note, your `CASE` expression doesn't actually achieve anything here. A `CASE` expression returns a scalar value, and uses [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to determine the data type of the returned value. You have 2 data types involved here, `int` and `decimal(p,s)` (I don't know what your defined precision and scale are, you don't tell us). As `decimal` has a higher precedence than `int`, then a `decimal(p,s)` is returned.

Comment: Effectively, for values that are a whole integer value in your `decimal` column, they are **explicitly** converted to an `int`, and then *implicitly* converted back to a `decimal` with the same precision and scale that they originally had; achieving literally nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution

```
select *,
   case when
    amount = floor(amount) then FORMAT(amount, 'N0')
    else
    FORMAT(amount, 'N2')
    end as roundedPrice
from MyTable
```